# Running JMeter threads in sequential mode

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I have a test plan with 100 users and I would want to loop through them once for sake of debugging, hence one user once and second user and so on.  I know I can use Once only controller to limit one user being run only once. What other setting should I use so that users don't overlap each other.

Note:

> I don't want to rely on ramp up period to distance users.

Comment: If I am getting you correctly, you want to run one user at a time and followed by another user i.e. running your script for 100 users one-by-one. No concurrency of users, Right?

Comment: yup, this is what I want to do

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Option 1**: You can keep the user count as 1 and Loop count as 100 in your thread group. This way your script will be executed 100 times, without concurrency of users and one user at a time. you can use CSV file if you want to change the user login credentials and other data at each loop starting i.e. different data for different user.

**Option 2**: Another solution is (a kind of workaround and it will too provide what you need), add 100 thread groups to your test plan in JMeter. Keep the User and Loop count as 1 in each thread group i.e. copy-paste the same and select the option **"Run Test Group consecutively"** in your test plan. You will get the desired result.

[image]

You can add **Tree Listener** to see if you are getting sequential requests or not.

Comment: and I did not have to once only controller :)

Comment: Yes, right you don't need to :)